# Rename dictionary keys ONLY fo specific value

Tags: dictionary, key, rename

I have a list of dictionaries in Python called 'Movies' where every dictionary shows the same keys for a movie:
(i.e "Title","Produced by,'Release dates' etc.).
Unfortunatley, I found out that some of these dictionaries in the list have a key called 'Release date" instead of 'Release dates'.

So my task is to change their name in order to have all dictionary with the same key "Release dates".
I tried this:

```
for dic in Movies:
          for k,v in dic.items():
                if dic[k] == 'Release date':
                           dic[k]='Release dates'
```

Unfortunately, when I try the following check:

```
print([m.keys() for m in Movies])
```

it still returns the old keys without any change

I don't know where I'm wrong

Answer (score 0):

Ok, maybe I find the solution. The Problem was due to the fact that in some dictionaries it couldn't find the key name to substitute so I have to pass a check. Here the workaround:

```
for dic in Movies:
    if 'Release date' in dic:
        dic['Release dates']=dic.pop('Release date')
print(Movies)
```